# Extract data from variables inside multiple callbacks in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm ok with javascript and callbacks, but I'm getting really annoyed at this and need to call on the the world of stackoverflow for help.

I have written a function, to be used in the following way:

```
var meth = lib.funcTion(a,b); // meth should hold an array of properties { c, d } once executed
```

So now inside lib.js, we have a structure like:

```
exports.funcTion = function (a,b) {
    database.connect(params, function(err,get){
          get.query(querylang, function(err, results){
                 var varsIwantToReturn = { var1: results[i].foo, var2: results[i].bar };
          });
    });
// Now how do i return 'varsIwantToReturn'?
};
```

I have seen some things about incorporating callback() into the function, but I'm not exactly sure how this works. I've also seen some people use exec() - again, im not sure on how or why to use it.

Please help :) thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's all asynchronous so if you attempt to return it - it'll return undefined. In JavaScript (Sans the new `yield` keyword) functions execute from top to bottom synchronously. When you make an IO call like a database call - it still executes synchronously. In fact- when `varIwantToReturn` gets population the function has long run and terminated.

What is left is to do the same thing async functions like `database.connect` and `get.query` do and have the function take a callback:

```
exports.function = function (a,b, callback) {
    database.connect(params, function(err,get){
          if(err) return callback(err, null); // don't suppress errors
          get.query(querylang, function(err, results){
               if(err) return callback(err, null); // don't suppress errors
               var varsIwantToReturn = { var1: results[i].foo, var2: results[i].bar };
               callback(null, varsIwantToReturn);
         });
    });
};
```

Then you'd call it like

```
myExportedFunction(myA,myB, function(err, resp){
    if(err) recoverFromError(err);
    // varsIWantToReturn are contained in `resp`
});
```

Comment: I made this CW since this is probably a duplicate. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Ben, will give this a go. As you've explained it, makes perfect sense though. BBS

Comment: @user2869420 check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call it's not the same question but it's about the same problem

Comment: Just one last question, what is the significance of the 'null' in the callback()?

Comment: @user2869420 it is the NodeJS "errback" convention - it's what Node uses in its APIs to overcome the lack of asynchronous exceptions - the callback function must resolve _exactly once_ and must have either an error set and a response be null or vice versa. It's a convention to help you work with other peoples' code. Personally I'd rather use a stronger abstraction that doesn't require nesting or silly null parameters like promises - but if you're using callbacks it is desirable to use the convention.

Comment: Ok thanks Ben.
If you have a method which you think would be better, open to hear it. I've only been using nodejs for a short period and this way seemed most practical. Cheers.

Comment: @user2869420 Promises! I personally use Bluebird, see the examples here https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird

Comment: Great, I'll give it a go, thanks :) yet another nodejs library to investigate! Cheers